# Looping between /dev/sda1: recovering journal and login screen

Tags: login, ssd, login-screen, recovery-mode

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm stuck between the login screen and a `/dev/sda1: recovering journal` screen. After it goes away I'm back at the login screen.

Login wont work as a guest user either.

Computer does have a nvidia card, the drivers are the default ones that come with the distro, selected from the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

1. Boot into Recovery mode.
2. Repair broken packages.
3. Login works.